# Airflow Plugin Hosting HTML Directory

Tags: python, flask, airflow

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Airflow (2.3.3) to host the html output that's generated from great expectations. (0.1.5). I'm able to get it to load the index.html page, but as soon as I click any of the links within, it directs me to an "Airflow 404 Page cannot be found." page.

Here is my plugin:

```py
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_appbuilder import expose, BaseView as AppBuilderBaseView
import os

class GreatExpectationsView(AppBuilderBaseView):

    @expose('/')
    def list(self):
        return self.render_template("index.html", content="")

v_appbuilder_view = GreatExpectationsView()

v_appbuilder_package = {
    "name": "Great Expectations",
    "category": "Browse",
    "view": v_appbuilder_view,
}

bp = Blueprint(
    "great_expectation",
    __name__,
    template_folder="/opt/great_expectations",
    static_folder='/opt/great_expectations/static',
    static_url_path='/greatexpectationsview/static'
)


class AirflowGEPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "great_expectation"
    appbuilder_views = [v_appbuilder_package]
    flask_blueprints = [bp]
```

This is the folder structure of the html generated by great expectations

```
/opt/great_expectations/
|-- expectations
|   `-- src
|       `-- dag1
|           `-- warning.html
|-- index.html
|-- static
|   |-- fonts
|   |   `-- HKGrotesk
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-Bold.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-BoldItalic.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-Italic.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-Light.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-LightItalic.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-Medium.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-MediumItalic.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-Regular.otf
|   |       |-- HKGrotesk-SemiBold.otf
|   |       `-- HKGrotesk-SemiBoldItalic.otf
|   |-- images
|   |   |-- favicon.ico
|   |   |-- glossary_scroller.gif
|   |   |-- iterative-dev-loop.png
|   |   |-- logo-long-vector.svg
|   |   |-- logo-long.png
|   |   |-- short-logo-vector.svg
|   |   |-- short-logo.png
|   |   `-- validation_failed_unexpected_values.gif
|   `-- styles
|       |-- data_docs_custom_styles_template.css
|       `-- data_docs_default_styles.css
`-- validations
    `-- src
        `-- dag1
            `-- warning
                |-- 20220914-170251-src_dag1
                |   `-- 20220914T170251.386427Z
                |       `-- 1811b6d2fab709c0e35cab11873288dc.html
                `-- 20220914-182123-src_dag1
                    `-- 20220914T182123.138118Z
                        `-- 1811b6d2fab709c0e35cab11873288dc.html
```

The links are attempting to route me to the html files in validations/src/dag1/warning/...

Any help on how I need to configure the plugin for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my issue. I just needed to tweak the `static_folder` and `static_url_path` options to this:

```
    bp = Blueprint(
        "great_expectation",
        __name__,
        template_folder="/opt/great_expectations",
        static_folder='/opt/great_expectations',
        static_url_path='/greatexpectationsview'
    )
```